# Xenserver 7 does not see new raid array just added on Dell R710 server

Tags: raid, xen, dell, xenserver

I have a question regarding how Xenserver 7.0 sees and add local storage raid arrays from a Dell R710 server.

Originally, the server came with a raid 5 setup of 4 hard drives, for a total of 800GB of space. I installed Xenserver on top of this raid array, which were the only array on the server. As you might expected, this created a "Local Storage" in Xenserver of the disk type LVM. By this time, the server still has two extra hard drive slots sits empty.

Fast forward a week or so, my CTO hands me two extra Seagate hard drives, each has 4 TB worth of disk space. I was tasked to add those extra storage in the Xenserver hypervisor. So I went ahead and plugged those two HDs into the R710 which the Xenserver sits on, rebooted the server and went into the PERC6/i Integrated BIOS Configuration Utility which is the raid controller my server uses. Here in the raid controller bios menu, I found out that the original 4 hard drives are configured to be virtual disk 0, with raid 5 configuration. So I went ahead and created another raid array using the Bios, I was only giving the option of adding another virtual disk outside of virtual disk 0, with raid 0 or raid 1, so I went ahead and created a virtual disk 1 that has total of 4 TB of storage space with raid 0 setup (Dell PERC6/i only supports individual disks of up to 2 TB of space, so it can only see my 4TB disks as 2TB individual disks, hence the total storage space of 4 TB). I saved the settings then reboot the server, and waited until the Xenserver menu were displayed.

Here is where it gets weird. I know that I need to create a new SR using the Xenserver with the new storage space that I added with a new raid array, but it seems that Xenserver does not see the new virtual disk 1 that I created in the dell server using raid 0 configuration. I went to the console and used `fdisk -l`, and the command did not return the new virtual disk that I just created, of course the Xenserver's adding a new storage repository feature can not be completed for me, since the new storage space were not being read by Xenserver.

So I need some help to make Xenserver to "see" my new virtual disk created by another raid array, or do I need to reinstall Xenserver all over again, so this time i can create one LVM partition across virtual disk 0 and virtual disk 1 that are created by two different raid configurations in the same server? Can this even be done? I am new to server storage, so this might seems a common configuration problem.

One more thing to address, the 4 hard disk that sits in the Dell server originally are SAS hds, the two new HDs that I am adding are regular SATA disks, thus they can not be added to the same raid array by default, I believe they have to form their own raid configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Following the XenServer Hardware Compatibility List seems that PERC6/i raid controller is compatible until version 6.5.

http://hcl.xensource.com/storagecontrollers/?storagecontrollersupport__version=5&vendor=3

Comment: I am also having a weird problem of windows server 2016 installation media not detecting any Hard disks and complaint about lack of driver detection, this might have something to do with it as well. As it went well in an older version of VMware hypervisor that I have with another older Dell server I got.